# How to add " ' chars as themselves in variables?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

I'm little new with scripting, so here we go:

I want to add several different variables to one variables, which is easily done with `var1=test1
Var2=test2
Var3=$var1$var2`
But if the text is more complicated, and contains **' "** for example:

```
Var1= "I'm "dead" and"
Var2= "not "alive" nowadays"
Var3=$Var1$Var2
```

This would result in

> ./test.sh:  16: ./test.sh: I'm dead and: not found
>   ./test.sh: 17: ./test.sh: not alive nowadays: not found

But I wanted it to be a textstring that says:

> I'm "dead" and not "alive" nowadays

Need this to via input execute a complicated long command-string

Am I making any sense?

Comment: Use one inside other `var='""'` or `var="''"` or use escaping `var=\'\"`

Comment: @Ivan tried that, it printed the \chars..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `here-doc` and avoid error prone escaping:

```
# populate var1
read -r var1<<-'EOF'
I'm "dead" and
EOF

# populate var2
read -r var2<<-'EOF'
not "alive" nowadays
EOF

# combine them
var3="$var1 $var2"
echo "$var3"
```

```
I'm "dead" and not "alive" nowadays
```

Comment: only resulted in an empty line over here, and I just copied what you wrote (added or course the top and made it executable)

Comment: you're correct, that one worked, strange that it didn't work when I copied it from here.. well, is there anyway to incorporate the $@ somewhere?, Isn't that suppose to add all arguments that where added after the .sh file?  Like test.sh testing testing..

Comment: Replace `'EOF'` with `EOF` (i.e. remove quotes around `EOF`) then it will allow use of `"$@"` inside here-doc.

Comment: Somehow the #!/bin/bash  had changed to #!/bin/sh, that's why it didn't work for me the first try..

Comment: You're s genius!, Let's say I want to "run" that line as a command, do I just remove the echo and write : $var3 on a line? In the same script if course..

Comment: `"$var3"` with quotes

Comment: @anubhava Still got issue with running it as a command, it seems like runs the while answer as one command, and not the first "word" as the command and the rest as arguments.

Comment: Sorry didn't understand what you meant by `runs the while answer as one command, and not the first "word" as the command`. Can you edit the question and show where exactly is the problem?